# Databinding: pass null as argument

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

How can I pass `null` as argument via databinding?

when it just

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.switchFunction(null)}"
```

I get `cannot find method switchFunction(java.lang.Object)` exception.

My ViewModel function is

```
fun switchFunction(param: MyClass?) {
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turned out, it's preaty easy - just need to specify type of `null`:

```
<data>
    <import type="classes.MyClass" />
</data>
...
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.switchFunction((MyClass) null)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that. Generated data binding code automatically checks for null values and avoid null pointer exceptions

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#null_coalescing_operator